# Session login page

Tags: asp.net

i Have created a web page, i have to login and then immediately the users sessions should be activated, in the backend i have a table which has the details of all the users which can be viewed by admin(ie me). the user can view olny his details  during the session. how to do it. give me some idea.

Comment: start develop the page..do the login page..do the db connection..try to login...create the session to hold the user id..insert into the table user login and logut time so the admin can track it..

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading about Membership in ASP.NET which provides a lot of built-in functionality for your needs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One part is the user to login, I think that all that is covered with examples, and you can add them with wizard and all that.

Now to find the user that are online

Get how many users are OnLine (logedin)

```
Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
```

To get their names (or what ever you like)

```
    StringBuilder sbRender = new StringBuilder();
    int Counter = 1;
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        if (u.IsOnline)
        {
            if (Counter > 1)
                sbRender.Append(" , ");

            sbRender.Append(u.UserName);
            Counter++;
        }
    }

    txtUserListOnLine.Text = sbRender.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to refer you here

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/security-basics-and-asp-net-support-cs

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs